# Projections in $C^*$-Algebras and Murray-von-Neumann Equivalence

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, equivalence-relations, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a unital $C^*$-algebra. Let $u$ be an isometry in $A$. Then we can write $1_A$, which is a projection, as $u^*u$. It is known that then $uu^*$ is also a projection. Can we produce any projection by such a decomposition?

In other words, given a projection $q \in A$, can we find an isometry $u \in A$ s.t. $q = uu^*$?

As a related question, is every projection in $A$ Murray-von-Neumann equivalent to $1_A$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely not.

Very simple example: Consider $X=[0,1]\cup[2,3]$ and the projection $p\in C(X)$ which is the indicator function of $[0,1]$, i.e. $p(t)=1$ for all $t\in[0,1]$ and $p(t)=0$ for all $t\in[2,3]$. If there existed an isometry $s\in C(X)$ such that $p=ss^*$, then since $C(X)$ is abelian we would have $p=1$, which is not the case.

Comment: Thank you, that’s helpful. Do you have any insight on my second question?

Comment: @LSK21 isn't your second question exactly the same as the first one?

Comment: Sorry, I guess I meant the third one.

Comment: @LSK21 Aren't all three questions exactly the same?

Comment: Oh yeah you're right. I was wondering if this was the case because I have been reading about finite and stably finite $C^*$-algebras, and there seem to be two definitions, one saying that $A$ is finite if $1_A$ is finite, and another that it is finite if all projections are finite. Are these definitions equivalent?

Comment: @LSK21 how is this question related? Anyway, yes these are equivalent for unital algebras, check Rordam's blue book on K theory, chapter 5

Comment: Thanks for the reference. The relation is thin I admit, I had something mixed up in my head when I asked the question. Hence my confusion about the three same questions as well.